# SQL unexpectedly rounding down DateTime2 results

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have an update command in our program that will compare all fields in the where clause as a sort of consistency check (if one of the fields don't match, something changed during the time we got the data, vs when we are actually running the update)

I have trouble with one of the fields, which is a type of DateTime. The actual Update command however is using a type of Datetime2, and so I run into the problem.

We have this code running on multiple sites for many years, and have had no problems, however one site started acting oddly when comparing the two times.

For some reason, when converting a type of Datetime to Datetime2, it rounded the query DOWN for no apparent reason. I've checked on multiple different databases (even on the same server, and other servers) and didn't find the same issue

I am using the below script as an example

```
declare @datetime datetime
set @datetime = '2016-07-11 13:50:11.957'

select CONVERT(datetime2,@datetime)`
```

ON the problem server this is giving me the following result

`2016-07-11 13:50:11.9566667`

On other servers

`2016-07-11 13:50:11.9570000`

I can see no reason why converting from Datetime to datetime2 it would decide to just take off time? is there a database setting somewhere that is causing this perhaps?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way SQL server processes `datetime` to `datetime2` conversion changed (<s>in 2014 if I recall</s>). This is intentional and documented (will find a link).

Newer versions represent the `datetime` more appropriately with `datetime2` and show the value accurate to 1/300 of a second, not `0.000`, `0.003` or `0.007` of a second.

Edit: Correction, the change was in SQL Server 2016. [Breaking Changes in SQL Server 2016 (13.x)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/breaking-changes-to-database-engine-features-in-sql-server-2016?view=sql-server-2017#SQL15):

> Under database compatibility level 130, implicit conversions from
>   datetime to datetime2 data types show improved accuracy by accounting
>   for the fractional milliseconds, resulting in different converted
>   values. Use explicit casting to datetime2 datatype whenever a mixed
>   comparison scenario between datetime and datetime2 datatypes exists.
>   For more information, see this [Microsoft Support Article](https://support.microsoft.com/help/4010261).

Edit: Going to cover a comment the OP made below: *" It still doesn't explain why SQL server feels that it is "more accurate" to remove time instead of just adding 000's"*. This isn't true, SQL Server, with the new versions, isn't removing (or adding) any time and that is exactly the point of the new conversion rules; as the old conversion did remove/add time.

It's a common misconception that `datetime` is accurate to 1/1000 of a second, as it shows 3 decimal places, for example `2016-07-11 13:50:11.957`. This, like I said though, is a misconception and is wrong. `datetime` is accurate to **1/300** of a second, and this is why the last digit in any `datetime` is `0.000`, `0.003` and `0.007`. That's because the values that don't end in 0 are *really* `0.003333333~` and `0.00666666~`.

This is why on the new versions, when converting to a `datetime2(7)` a value like `2016-07-11 13:50:11.957` is shown as `2016-07-11 13:50:11.9566667`, as that's far more accurate. The **old** versions of SQL Server were actually rounding the value like `2016-07-11 13:50:11.9566666~` to `2016-07-11 13:50:11.9570000`, meaning it **added** `0.0003333~` to the value. For a value like `2019-07-12 14:13:12.1233333~` the conversion would **remove** `0.0003333~` from the value, to make `2019-07-12 14:13:12.1230000`.

This is why the newer versions give a different value. They are **more accurate**

Another edit: A point raised by David Dubois was that for the below SQL (or similar) they would expect the `PRINT` statement to appear on SQL Server 2016+:

```
DECLARE @dt2 datetime2,
        @dt datetime;
SET @dt = '2016-07-11T13:50:11.957';

SET @dt2 = @dt;

IF @dt2 = @dt
    PRINT 'The Same (Implicit)'; --Implicit is important
```

If you try this though, it doesn't. As I mention in the comments, this is actually covered in the above quote, but to reiterate the specific sentence:

> Use explicit casting to datetime2 datatype whenever a mixed
>   comparison scenario between datetime and datetime2 datatypes exists.

If you change the above to explicit casting, as the documentation tells you to, the query works as you expect:

```
DECLARE @dt2 datetime2,
        @dt datetime;
SET @dt = '2016-07-11T13:50:11.957';

SET @dt2 = @dt;

IF @dt2 = CONVERT(datetime2(7),@dt)
    PRINT 'The Same (Explicit)';
```

*Note on SQL Server 2014 or prior, the above would return the `PRINT` statement for both the Implicit and Explicit conversions.*

Comment: Hi thanks for this, i found that by changing the compatibility options on the server i was able to replicate the issue. It still doesn't explain why SQL server feels that it is "more accurate" to remove time instead of just adding 000's

Comment: It's not adding time though @Sean . In fact changing the value to `.3330000` is **removing** time in the old conversion rules; it's removing `.0003333~` seconds from the `datetime` value.

Comment: @Sean I've added some more detail for you to explain why your statement *" SQL server feels that it is "more accurate" to remove time instead of just adding 000's "* is not **removing** time in the new versions.

Comment: What I find odd is that the result compares not equal.  set @dt2=@dt if @dt<>@dt2 print 'not equal'  To perform the comparison it should convert the datetime to datetime2 and get the same value.  What is it comparing?

Comment: @DavidDubois the reason is because the `datetime` will have the value `2016-07-11T13:50:11.957` (which is equal to `2016-07-11T13:50:11.956666~`) where as the `datetime(2)` will have the value `2016-07-11T13:50:11.9566667` (note not `666~`). `2016-07-11T13:50:11.956666~` <> `2016-07-11T13:50:11.9566667` and so the values aren't the same.

Comment: When comparing two values of different types it converts the value with lower precedence to the other and then compares.  When it compares 
 it converts the datetime to datetime2 it should get the same result as it did in the assignment.         https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @DavidDubois to quote the quote I made above: *"Use explicit casting to datetime2 datatype whenever a **mixed comparison scenario** between datetime and datetime2 datatypes exists."* Try `IF @dt2 = CONVERT(datetime2(7),@dt)` and you get the behaviour your after. What you are describing is all documented in the links in my post. [DB<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a1c845641c547f73dce3073358ec6f27)

Comment: @Larnu, that does help explain it all, breaks all our code, but at least i know why now! thanks again